# Is it feasible to have an algorithm in C++ which calls a Fortran program for the heavily computation parts?

Tags: c++, algorithm, fortran, greedy, hill-climbing

I am developing an algorithm that has a large numerical computation part. My project supervisor recommended me to use Fortran because of this and so for the last weeks I've been work on it (so far so good). It would be a new version of an algorithm of his, which is basically a lot of numerical computing.

Mine, however, would have more "logic" to it. Without going into much detail, the brute force approach is done using just fortran because it's just 95% of reading from a file and doing the operations. However, the aim of the project is to provide an efficient algorithm to do this, I had been thinking about methods and wanted to start with a Greedy approach (something like Hill Climbing) and that got me thinking that for this part in particular, maybe it would be better to write the algorithm in C++ instead of Fortran.

So basically, how hard do you think it would be to develop the algorithm "logic" in C++ and then call Fortran whenever the bulk of the numerical computation has to be performed. Would it be worth it? Or should I just stick with one of the two languages?

Sorry if it is a very ignorant question but I can't get an idea of whether writing an algorithm such as Hill Climbing would be more difficult if done with Fortran instead of C++ and the benefits of Fortran in this case would be worth it.

Thanks for your time and have a nice day!

Comment: C++ is designed to be able to call anything that C can call. And compatibility between C and Fortran have been very good the last few decades. In short, it's as easy to call Fortran function from C++ as from C, the only C++-specific thing is that you need to declare the functions as `extern "C"` (the `"C"` is for C calling convention, the actual language the function is programmed in is irrelevant).

Comment: It is certainly possible. But whether it is worth doing is entirely opinion based and thus off-topic for this site.

Comment: It is actually possible to write algorithms effectively in both languages. Both modern Fortran and modern C++ are effective for both "numerical computation" and "algorithm logic" - if they are used with sufficient skill. Your individual skills and prejudices (your supervisor preference for Fortran for numerics, yours for C++ for "algorithm logic") are key factors in both your thinking.  The reality is that either language can be used for your task, or a combination of the two.  There are advantages and disadvantages with any such choice.

Comment: I would also add this: the answer also depends on the context. Questions that come to mind: is this part of a larger project? (then the language usually used for the project may matter). Does the lab use usually Fortran or C++? How will your project be used, by whom? Does the staff know both languages? Are there plans to switch to C++ on the long run?

Comment: It is entirely possible, using `iso_c_binding` intrinsic module in Fortran. All you need is a good reference book on modern Fortran. I'd recommend "Modern Fortran Explained: Incorporating Fortran 2018" by Metcalf et al. I had this same question 4 years ago, and we ended up writing the core of the software in Fortran 2008, with the necessary interfaces to C/C++ and other languages. I don't regret the decision now, as the native array-based syntax of Fortran and its intrinsic functions were really handy during the development.